# Restrict tweepy's api.search to a certain user

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Using tweepy's api.search function works perfectly fine until I incorporate a filter.

In this case I'm trying to search for "EL 44 from:unfavorablesemi"
Searching through Twitter with [an advanced search](https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&q=EL%2044%20from%3Aunfavorablesemi&src=typd)

returns exactly what I am looking for.

However when I try and use tweepy's api.search function with a query of "EL 44 from:unfavorablesemi" nothing is returned.

```
import tweepy

consumer_key = "ckey"
consumer_secret = "csecret"
access_token = "atoken"
access_secret = "asecret"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

query = "EL 44 from:unfavorablesemi"

for result in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=query).items(1):
    print(result.text.encode("utf-8"))
```

Also, I can't search through the results of api.user_timeline as it would only return the last ~3200 tweets.

Answer (score 0):

Reading over the [docs](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html) shows there is a parameter in the api reference that does what you need. By default, wait_on_rate_limit is set to false. Please establish the API in the following way:

```
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
```